# How do you expand a REG_EXPAND_SZ in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, registry, environment-variables

I'd like to be able to expand the value of a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` retrieved with `reg query <KEY> /v <VALUE>`.

How do you expand an environment variable containing environment variables (surrounded with `%`)?
For example, I want to expand `%systemroot%\system32\config` contained in `x` to `C:\Windows\system32\config`.

Comment: Just use it. That's all you need do.

Comment: @Noodles That's not true. For example, if the environment variable `x` is `%UserProfile%\Documents`, where `echo '%x%'` results in `'%UserProfile%\Documents'`, you cannot use `dir "%x%"` or similar operations. The string contains a literaly percent symbol and normally would not be treated specially as an environment variable, even if it's desired.

Comment: You could also use delayed expansion

Comment: @SomethingDark How would this be done, exactly? It'd make a good answer if it works. I could only see using delayed expansion to expand a single variable name, not a name including `%` and additional items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`call set`](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html).

```
:: This code is for a batch file, as expansion works differently.
set x=%%systemroot%%\system32\config
:: '%x%' is now '%systemroot%\system32\config'
call set "y=%x%"
```

`call` will [parse its code block twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/1530134), so `call set "y=%x%"` will first expand to `set "y=%systemroot%\system32\config"`, and then when the set is called, it is expanded (on my system) to `set "y=C:\Windows\system32\config"`.